# Damaged preference file in /bin/sh

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, macbook-pro, osx-yosemite

Today in Drive Genius 3, I ran the “Verify Preferences” function in *Repair*. It yielded this strange result:

> **/bin/sh: xargs: command not found**

The only option Drive Genius gives is to remove the file, and it seems like I probably shouldn't remove a file in */bin*!
Can somebody help me fix this problem and tell me what I should do? My specs are below. Thanks!

MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)
OS X Yosemite (10.10)
Error was found using Drive Genius 3.2.4 running on a bootable USB drive

Answer (score 0):

Dopn’t panic! The file `/bin/sh` is simply a binary file for the shell on the system which is `bash`. Here is the output of me running `/bin/sh -version` on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) install:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Your removal of it is one thing, but if it was damaged it was damaged. So no matter whether via removal or being damaged… The file was not viable. So you would need to recover it in some way. And you can easily restore it.

Just get into some bootable Mac OS X 10.10 system and just copy the `/bin/sh` from there onto a USB flash drive or something. And then copy that `/bin/sh` back to your damaged system.  Make sure the permissions are `-r-xr-xr-x` by doing this:

```
sudo chmod 555 /bin/sh
```

…and all should be good!